# How to deal with the WIFI change network in android live?

Tags: android, video, live

when my apps accept push video live,my apps can see the vedio live normal.but when my apps change the network ,it will be lost the network connection，just like from wifi to network.So how to deal it?

Comment: In this case,you can check if wifi off and network connnected then show msg dialog "network error" .have you played your video in 3g or 2g?

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver for this to determine your network connection